# CRM 2016 api unauthorized access

Tags: wcf, dynamics-crm, crm

I wrote this code to connect to CRM on premise 2016 and retrieve some data.

Here it's

```
var credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password?", "domain");
            var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { Credentials = credentials })
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri("https://xxxtestenv.elluciancrmrecruit.com/api/data/v8.0/")
            };
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            var response = client.GetAsync("datatel_events?$orderby=datatel_eventname").Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var yourcustomobjects = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
```

but I get this error

> ```
>   response    {StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
> ```
>
> {
>     REQ_ID: b685b007-199b-4a4a-85cc-3a29684e5588
>     Date: Thu, 22 Sep 2016 19:27:35 GMT
>     Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
>     WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
>     WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
>     X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>     Connection: keep-alive
>     Content-Length: 49
>     Content-Type: text/plain
>   }}  System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it IFD enabled ?

Comment: yes it's , we can access it from anywhere . I found when I debug the code that httpclient has redirect link to another link which we use to login to crm. Does this sound normal to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using below code to connect to MS CRM on premise.

```
string strOrganizationUri = "https://{your domain}/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc";
            string strUserName = "{your domain username}";
            string strPassword = "{your domain password}";
            var organizationUriIFD = new Uri(strOrganizationUri);

            var credentials = new ClientCredentials();
            credentials.UserName.UserName = strUserName;
            credentials.UserName.Password = strPassword;

            IServiceConfiguration<IOrganizationService> config = ServiceConfigurationFactory.CreateConfiguration<IOrganizationService>(organizationUriIFD);
            IOrganizationService service;
            using (var serviceProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(config, credentials))
            {
                // This statement is required to enable early-bound type support.
                serviceProxy.ServiceConfiguration.CurrentServiceEndpoint.Behaviors.Add(new ProxyTypesBehavior());

                service = serviceProxy;

            }


            // Get the ID's of the current user and business unit.
            var who = new WhoAmIRequest();
            //retreive user data from the server.
            var whoResponse = (WhoAmIResponse)service.Execute(who);
```